# how to avoid increasing url in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django and learning it by developing small projects.
Currently i am creating login app.I am facing below issue,
i have written on form tag in one template:

```
<form method="GET" action="login_page/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type ="submit"> Login</button>
</form>
```

after clicking submit button i goes to login/page url.

And in the other template i have written below form tag,

```
<form method="GET" action= "Welcome/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type ="submit"> Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

and my urls are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login_page/', include('login.urls'))
]
```

urlpatterns=[

```
   #url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'),name='base'),
   url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='home'),
   url(r'^Welcome/$', views.WelcomeView.as_view(), name='Welcome'),
   #url(r'^Welcome/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Welcome.html'),name='Welcome'),
   url(r'^logout/$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Logout.html'),name='Logout'),
   url(r'^home/$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='home')
```

]

but the issue is as i goes on and click submit buttons url keeps increasing, like
    http://localhost:8000/login_page/
    localhost:8000/login_page/Welcome/
    localhost:8000/login_page/Welcome/login_page

and hence it gives error as it can not find 3rd url. how to correct it.
? can we go to views for action in form tag?

Comment: Your form should be a `POST`, not a `GET`

Comment: Go with slackmart's answer.  That's how you should do it, but the reason the URL is doing that is because you are passing a relative URL without a preceding `/`.  This just adds it to the end of the existing URL and doesn't go to the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the url template tag. By doing so, this helper template tag is gonna automatically replace the url with its correct url.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'Welcome' %}">
```

where `Welcome` is the url name,

```
url(r'^Welcome/$', views.WelcomeView.as_view(), name='Welcome'),
                                                      #  ^ this one
```

Do the same with the other urls.

Link to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Hey! @neeraj-kumar is right. The form method should be POST for both forms.

Answer (score 0):

First thing If your form using GET method then no need of {% csrf_token %} So remove it if you want GET method in form.

When you add new URL's from app urls then always use namespace concept that is better way to make difference between same URL of different apps

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login_page/', include('login.urls', namespace='login_page'))
                                               # ^ add namespace
]


<form method="GET" action= "{% url 'login_page:Welcome' %}">
        <button type ="submit"> Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey! You're right. The form method should be POST for both forms.